# compile .so with .h

Tags: c, gcc

I have three files:

```
list.c, recursive.c, recursive.h
```

the 2nd and third are the header and .c of an auxiliary function called: recursive.

The first one is a file that im trying to compile as a .so. It does an include of recursive.h with:

`#include "recursive.h"`

Normally i would compile it with:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o list.so list.c
```

but whenever i run the code from a client program i get the following:

```
./shell: symbol lookup error: /home/list.so: undefined symbol: recursive
```

Comment: Where is the function `recursive()` defined?

Comment: @Ctx its defined in recursive.c. Prototyped in recursive.h

Comment: Then you will probably have to link recursive.c also into list.so

Comment: @Ctx I read some answers suggesting the same on the internet. But i dont know how to link a .c

Comment: `gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o list.so list.c recursive.c`

Comment: @Ctx if i compile with your command it ignores the .h (there are vital structs there)

Comment: Did you forget to include it in `recursive.c`?

Comment: @Ctx opps... Indeed i did.

Comment: Hah! My crystalball is worth its money ;)

Comment: @Ctx absolutely hahah

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Ctx. The solution was to compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o list.so list.c recursive.c
```